# How to make a web scrap more human-like?

Tags: python, web-scraping

I have a web scrap script written in python and when I use it to a website it blocks me and says "you getting the page very fast. you might be a bot".

I tried adding `time.sleep()` to delay code but it always gets blocked. Is there any way to make this code a little slower?

I'm not sure why it should say so. Isn't it the same as viewing page from a website? What does it load that makes it not labelled as a bot but my script does?

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import re
import requests
import time
import sys
import csv

FIXED_WEB = "web.net"


def load_car_pages(seq, limit, i):
    time.sleep(10)
    html_web = requests.get(
        f"web.net/homepage",
        headers={
            'User-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:99.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/99.0',
            'Accept': "text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/avif,image/webp,/;q=0.8",
            'Accept-Language': "en-US,en;q=0.5",
            'Accept-Encoding': "gzip, deflate",
            'Upgrade-Insecure-Requests': '1',
            'Sec-Fetch-Dest': 'document',
            'Sec-Fetch-Mode': 'navigate',
            'Sec-Fetch-Site': 'none',
            'Sec-Fetch-User': '?1',
            'Te': 'trailers'
        }).text
    time.sleep(10)
    sup_me_patate = BeautifulSoup(html_web, 'lxml')
    headers = sup_me_patate.find_all('div', class_='sui-AtomCard-info') # find headers
    print(f"{headers}")

    for a in headers:
        string = str(a)
        href_pos = [m.start() for m in re.finditer('href=', string)]
        for pos in href_pos:
            slicing = string[pos + 6: string.find('"', pos + 6)]

            print(f"For Link: {slicing}")
            web_link = FIXED_WEB + slicing
            print(f"LINK: {web_link}")
            # limit = 25
            # i = 0
            time.sleep(10)
            try:
                car_web = requests.get(web_link, headers={
                    'User-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:99.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/99.0',
                    'Origin': FIXED_WEB,
                    "Access-Control-Request-Method": "GET",
                    'Accept-Language': "en-US,en;q=0.5",
                    'Accept-Encoding': "gzip, deflate",
                    'Request-Domain': 'web.net',
                    'Site': 'car',
                    'Referer': web_link,
                    "Sec-Fetch-Dest": "empty",
                    "Sec- Fetch-Mode": "cors",
                    "Sec-Fetch-Site": "same-origin",
                    "Te": "trailers",
                    'Connection': 'close'}).text

                soup = BeautifulSoup(web_link, "lxml")

                # with open(soup.title.string + ".html", 'w') as coolhtml:
                #     string = str(soup)
                #     coolhtml.write(string)
                #     sys.exit(0)
                 name = soup.find_all('h2',
                                     class_="mt-TitleBasic-title mt-TitleBasic-title--xs mt-TitleBasic-title--black")
                address = soup.find('p', class_="mt-CardUser-location").text
                phone_number = soup.find('span', class_='mt-LeadPhoneCall-linkText mt-LeadPhoneCall-linkText--small')\
                    .text

                j = 0
                for b in name:
                    if j == 8:
                        real_name = b.text
                        print(b.text)
                    j += 1
   
                # some costansts
                NAME = real_name
                ADDRESS = address
                PHONE_NUMBER = phone_number

                header = ['Name', 'Address', 'Phone Number']
                data = [ADDRESS, PHONE_NUMBER, NAME]

                with open("info.csv", 'a', encoding='UTF8') as csv_numbers:
                    writer = csv.writer(csv_numbers)
                    writer.writerow(data)

                i += 1
                print(i)
                if i == limit:
                    print("it prints...")
                    limit += 35
                    seq += 1
                    load_car_pages(seq, limit, i)

            except Exception as ACX:
                print(f"Bro Exception occurred::{ACX}...")
            # continue


def main():
    # get_car_links()
    load_car_pages(0, 35, 0)


main()
```

Answer (score 1):

You're asking too many overloaded questions all at once (even though they're somewhat related in your particular context). I'll only answer the one in your title: How to make a web scraper more human-like?

That question is too open-ended to be definitively answered. New methods of bot detection will continue to be developed, as well as ways to bypass them.

That being said: a couple highlights off the top of my head:

- Browsers send & receive *a lot* of metadata, like user agent, headers, cookies, runtime JavaScript, etc. Bare HTTP requests look very different from that.
- Browser automation systems behave very differently from humans by default: they don't really use the mouse, they click buttons instantly at their exact centers, etc
- Browser automation detection and detection bypass is a rabbit hole: [Can a website detect when you are using Selenium with chromedriver?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33225947/can-a-website-detect-when-you-are-using-selenium-with-chromedriver)

Comment: as per you answer, imma gonna look once at Selenium. and your second point was very a nice hint tbh. clicking buttons very fast is a way telling you that there is smth sus. Imma look if I can slow it down using python